# Start animation before loop() reaches end

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-animated

In my app I have a series of objects, that I animate one by one.

The working code for the animation looks like that so far:

```
const fields = FIELDS.map( f => ({ scale:useRef( new Animated.Value( 1 ) ).current, offset:useRef( new Animated.Value( 0 ) ).current, f }) )

const animation = Animated.loop(
      Animated.stagger( 180, fields.map( ({ scale, offset }) => Animated.parallel( [
        Animated.sequence( [
          Animated.timing( scale, { ...OPTS, toValue:1.4 } ),
          Animated.timing( scale, { ...OPTS, toValue:1 } ),
        ] ),
        Animated.sequence( [
          Animated.timing( offset, { ...OPTS, toValue:-1.4 } ),
          Animated.timing( offset, { ...OPTS, toValue:0 } ),
        ] ), 
      ] ) ) ),
    { useNativeDriver:true }
)
```

See the [this Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@injecteer/graceful-yogurt) for the whole code (does NOT work in Web-mode, olny on emulator or real device!)

It looks like this:

[image]

The objects are "growing" and "shrinking" from 1 to 6.

Now I want to achieve the following "wave" effect:

When the object `(3)` is animated, the `(1)` should be animated as well.

When the object `(4)` is animated, the `(2)` should be animated as well.

So, the animation should be performed in 2 (or more) simultaneous waves, shifted by `2 * 180` ms.

How to configure the animation object for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, that a combination of `parallel` with `sequence` and `delay` would do the trick:

```
  const animation = Animated.loop(
    Animated.parallel( [
      Animated.stagger( DURATION, fields.map( blink ) ),
      Animated.sequence( [
        Animated.delay( DURATION * ( fields.length - 1 ) / 2 ),
        Animated.stagger( DURATION, fields.map( blink ) ),
      ] ),
    ] ),
    { useNativeDriver:true }
  )
```

See the [updated Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@injecteer/graceful-yogurt)